# a star in the sky thay moves back and forth way up in the sky

Tags: star

did anyone watch the sky in the west at 1:15 am.On 7-13-18. a star moving around in the greenup ky UT WOULD go back and forth

Comment: Yeah, probably so UFO kind of thing.

Comment: write as if the world was reading it.